# Excel Help - creating tables from data sets

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create a table from a list which has the following components, to show how many **users** within a **company** have completed a course within a date

Please see image for how the data set looks:

[image]

So for example, Dave A has completed 2 courses in Jan-17 for the same company, but I'm struggling to calculate this in one formula as the data set is very large. there's over 40 training courses and numerous users within each company.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What exactly do you want to calculate?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the late reply on this, I'm looking to count how many individual users have completed a course for each company, when I pivot however, it brings back all the users for each company, so if Dave A has completed three courses, it counts him each time, where I want to count him only once.

Answer (score 0):

Pivot table (as suggested by pnuts) would be best in my opinion; however, if you need a formula try COUNTIFS:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,C:C,C2,D:D,D2)
```

Per your data:

It checks all of the A column (name range) and compares it to cell A2

It checks all of the C column (company range) and compares it to cell C2

It checks all of the D column (complete date range) and compares it to cell D2

If all three criteria are equal it will add 1 to the count.

You can make a list of the names in the list and put this formula in for all of them using whatever cell their name first appears as the criteria (compare cell).